# Using LEAD to get next distinct date

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am calculating the next_order_date for each order in a Spark SQL query. However, when multiple orders occur on the same date for a customer, the next_order_date is not being computed accurately. I want to ensure that the next_order_date corresponds to the next distinct order date for the same customer.

Example:

Consider the following transaction records:

| customer_key | order_id | order_date | quantity | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34603 | 1 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 |
| 34603 | 2 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 |
| 34603 | 3 | 2022-10-08 | 4 | 499 |
| 34603 | 4 | 2023-07-12 | 2 | 499 |
| 34603 | 5 | 2023-10-15 | 1 | 499 |

The expected next_order_date for each order:

| customer_key | order_id | order_date | quantity | amount | next_order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34603 | 1 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 2 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 3 | 2022-10-08 | 4 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 4 | 2023-07-12 | 2 | 499 | 2023-10-15 |
| 34603 | 5 | 2023-10-15 | 1 | 499 | NULL |

This is what I tried -

```sql
WITH ranked_transactions AS (
        SELECT
        t.*,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.customer_key ORDER BY t.order_date) AS order_rank
        FROM transaction_records t
    )
SELECT
    customer_key,
    order_id,
    order_date,
    quantity,
    amount,
    order_rank,
    LEAD(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_key, order_rank ORDER BY order_date) AS next_order_date
FROM ranked_transactions
```

But the next_order_date is calculating incorrectly. Below is the output of the code:

| customer_key | order_id | order_date | quantity | amount | order_rank | next_order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34603 | 1 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 1 | 2022-10-08 |
| 34603 | 2 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 1 | 2022-10-08 |
| 34603 | 3 | 2022-10-08 | 4 | 499 | 1 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 4 | 2023-07-12 | 2 | 499 | 2 | 2023-10-15 |
| 34603 | 5 | 2023-10-15 | 1 | 499 | 3 | NULL |

Explanation:

In the SQL query, I utilize a common table expression (WITH clause) named ranked_transactions to calculate the order_rank for each transaction within the same customer, ensuring that orders with the same date receive the same rank. Then, using the LEAD window function, I calculate the next_order_date by partitioning the data by customer_key and ordering it by order_date. However, this approach does not consider distinct dates for the next order.

How to calculate the next_order_date correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See next example

```
select t.*,d.next_date
from transactions t
left join (
  select customer_key,order_date
     ,lead(order_date)over(partition by customer_key order by order_date)next_date
  from transactions
  group by customer_key,order_date
 ) d on d.customer_key=t.customer_key and d.order_date=t.order_date
```

Output

| customer_key | order_id | order_date | quantity | amount | next_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34603 | 1 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 2 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 3 | 2022-10-08 | 4 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 4 | 2023-07-12 | 2 | 499 | 2023-10-15 |
| 34603 | 5 | 2023-10-15 | 1 | 499 | null |

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another w-function to determine the next distinct order date.

```sql
WITH ranked_transactions AS (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.customer_key ORDER BY t.order_date) AS order_rank
    FROM transaction_records t
),
next_order_dates AS (
    SELECT
        customer_key,
        MIN(order_date) AS next_distinct_order_date
    FROM ranked_transactions
    GROUP BY customer_key
)
SELECT
    t.customer_key,
    t.order_id,
    t.order_date,
    t.quantity,
    t.amount,
    t.order_rank,
    n.next_distinct_order_date AS next_order_date
FROM ranked_transactions t
LEFT JOIN next_order_dates n ON t.customer_key = n.customer_key
ORDER BY t.customer_key, t.order_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not wedded to the idea of using Window Functions, try the following.

NB: I did this in [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/), not [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org) though.

```
sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41 872ba256cbf61d9290b571c0e6d82a20c224ca3ad82971edc46b29818d5dalt1
zlib version 1.2.11
gcc-11.4.0
sqlite> -- NB: This is done in SQLite (3.37.2), not Apache Spark
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.transaction_records;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE transaction_records AS
WITH
        _values(customer_key,order_id,order_date,quantity,amount) AS ( VALUES
        ('34603','1','2022-10-08','1','499'),
        ('34603','2','2022-10-08','1','499'),
        ('34603','3','2022-10-08','4','499'),
        ('34603','4','2023-07-12','2','499'),
        ('34603','5','2023-10-15','1','499')
) SELECT * FROM _values;

WITH 
        _next_order_date(customer_key,order_id,order_date,quantity,amount,next_order_date) AS (
                SELECT t1.*, MAX(t1.order_date, t2.order_date)
                FROM transaction_records t1
                JOIN transaction_records t2 ON
                        t1.customer_key==t2.customer_key AND t2.order_date > t1.order_date
                GROUP BY t1.customer_key, t1.order_id)
SELECT t1.*, nod.next_order_date
FROM transaction_records t1
LEFT JOIN _next_order_date nod USING(order_id);
```

Output:

| customer_key | order_id | order_date | quantity | amount | next_order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34603 | 1 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 2 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 3 | 2022-10-08 | 4 | 499 | 2023-07-12 |
| 34603 | 4 | 2023-07-12 | 2 | 499 | 2023-10-15 |
| 34603 | 5 | 2023-10-15 | 1 | 499 |  |

Answer (score 1):

We can use second parameter ( `offset`) of lag() or lead() functions to take next or previous value for groups of rows. Calculate number of rows in current group(cnt) and position (row_number) of current row in group (rn). Shift value to first row of next group is =cnt-rn+1.

See example

```
with t as(
select * 
     -- order row_number by date
  ,row_number()over(partition by customer_key,order_date order by order_id)rn
     -- count of order by date
  ,count(*)over(partition by customer_key,order_date )cnt
from transactions
)
select *
     -- next value shift=cnt-rn+1
  ,lead(order_date,cnt-rn+1)
      over(partition by customer_key order by order_date,order_id) next_date
     -- prev value shift=rn
  ,lag(order_date,rn)
      over(partition by customer_key order by order_date,order_id) prev_date
from t
```

Please note that  calculating `cnt` and `rn` - within (customer_key,order_date) range - we use `partition by customer_key,order_date` and `order by order_id`.

When taking next (previous) value we use `partition by customer_key` and  `order by order_date,order_id` - within (customer_key) range.

Output

| customer_key | order_id | order_date | quantity | amount | rn | cnt | next_date | prev_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34603 | 1 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 1 | 3 | 2023-07-12 | null |
| 34603 | 2 | 2022-10-08 | 1 | 499 | 2 | 3 | 2023-07-12 | null |
| 34603 | 3 | 2022-10-08 | 4 | 499 | 3 | 3 | 2023-07-12 | null |
| 34603 | 4 | 2023-07-12 | 2 | 499 | 1 | 1 | 2023-10-15 | 2022-10-08 |
| 34603 | 5 | 2023-10-15 | 1 | 499 | 1 | 1 | null | 2023-07-12 |

Shortly

```
select *
  ,lead(order_date,shift)
      over(partition by customer_key order by order_date,order_id) next_date
from (
   select * 
     ,count(*)over(partition by customer_key,order_date )
     -row_number()over(partition by customer_key,order_date order by order_id) 
     +1 shift
   from transactions
)t
```

Comment: I am keep getting this error in spark sql - "Cannot specify window frame for lead function.". Do you know why it is happening?

Comment: What do you have "under the hood" of spark? I think, if MySql, this not work. Other (SQL Server,PostgreSQL,SQLite ...) will work. Can you use 2 windows in query?

Comment: I'll add next answer without ``shift`` parameter for ``lead()``.